# What are the advantages of using Depends in FastAPI?

Tags: python, design-patterns, dependency-injection, fastapi, depends

I am studying the FastAPI framework and the principle of Dependency Injection, which is implemented in it using Depends. I have a question related to the expediency of using DI in those cases, which is given by well-known tutorials and examples from books.

For example, I have an endpoint handler function that uses dependency injection:

```py
@app.get(
    '/something',
    status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK,
    response_model=SomeModel,
)
def get_something_endpoint(service = Depends(SomeService)) -> SomeModel:
    return service.get_something()
```

I can do the same without using DI:

```py
@app.get(
    '/something',
    status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK,
    response_model=SomeModel,
)
def get_something_endpoint() -> SomeModel:
    return SomeService().get_something()
```

I don't understand why use DI in this case if it doesn't have any advantages in this simplest case:

- If the service implementation changes, you will have to change the endpoint handler function. What difference does it make where to do it, in the arguments or in the body of the function?
- The function actually gets a dependency automatically, it cannot be transferred from the outside, since the router connects directly to the FastAPI application.
- Maybe this case is too trivial? Maybe it doesn't matter what exactly to use here, but more complex cases can show the full power of DI?

I suspect that I do not understand either some features of the DI principle or the implementation of Depends in FastAPI. Please explain where I am wrong.

I tried to look at the examples in the tutorials and the FastAPI documentation, but I did not find an answer to my question. The documentation suggests using DI, but doesn't seem to explain why.

Comment: I don’t know the specifics of Depends, but in general, this kind of annotation would mean your function expects some instance that acts like `SomeService`, and you should be able to configure Depends elsewhere and decide/override what class exactly it’ll use. So you can change what object gets injected. It should of course act the same (duck typing), but may be implemented very differently.

Comment: @deceze However, there is no actual transfer of `SomeService`, since the default value is used. That is, an instance of the `SomeService` class is created. Of course, I can change this class to some other one, but I cannot pass some implementation of such an interface to the endpoint handler function. If I understood everything correctly.

Comment: There are multiple points: dependencies are resolved (and cached) hierarchically, so if `SomeService` needed an instance of `AnotherService` and `FooService`, and `SomeOtherService` needed both as well, they're only resolved and initialized once - think of dependencies as being small, composable bits that you put together to get what you want. Also think of dependencies in a wider context; you can have a dependency that is `post_owned_by_current_user` for example, which means that your controllers actual implementation becomes very lean, and you get the logic separated out from the endpoint.

Comment: You usually give `Depends` a function which does whatever logic is necessary to create and verify the dependency, so in your case it could be `get_some_service` and you could change whatever `some_service` means inside your function. Classes as dependencies are useful when they represent a set of request arguments, such as shown in https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/classes-as-dependencies/#classes-as-dependencies_1

Comment: @MatsLindh I can change the logic of the dependency in `get_some_service`, however, I can also do this in the `__init__` method of the class itself. In this case, I don't see the need to use the interface (base class) if I can change the dependency directly in the `SomeService` class. Yes, using the function adds flexibility, but I don't understand why I need this flexibility. Can you give a specific small example in which, in your opinion, such a function could be used (without the DI hierarchy, I think I understood that)?

Comment: You can't just switch which implementation gets returned in `SomeClass` - but you can always create a proxy class that proxies and requests further back and use that as your dependency. If you suddenly want `get_some_service` to depend on some other property of the request, you can add that as a dependency to the function and it'll get resolved automagically.

Comment: But I'm not going to argue that _you need something_. Only you know. Do whatever works for you, but `Depends` with the common thought of "i need <this specific thing>" instead of thinking of it as "just get me a service instance" is usually more helpful (and means that you might not need the service itself in your controller definition at all, just that it receives the dependencies it has to given objects). `Depends` let you inject an already created service to that dependency in those cases, where the function can retrieve and verify whatever object you return to your controller (or error out